# Remove everything except child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent, children

```
<div class="parent">
   <span>sometext</span>
   plain text
   <input class="child">
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <span>sometext</span>
   plain text
   <input class="child">
</div>
<div class="parent">
   <span>sometext</span>
   plain text
   <input class="child">
</div>
```

How do I safely remove everything in `.parent` except `.child`?

I'm using this code (where `items` is a stack of `.child` and `each` is a `.child`)

```
items.each(function(){
    $(this).parent().children().each(function(){
       if ($(this).hasClass('child'))
          // do something
       else
          $(this).remove();
    });

    $(this).unwrap(); // remove parent, keep only .child
});
```

But it doesn't handle plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said

> There can be more than one `.child` inside `.parent`, we keep only a first one. So If there are three, second and third should be removed.

and that

> `items` is a stack of `.child` and each is a `.child`

Okay, then this is what I would do:

```
items.parent('.parent').each(function() {
    var parent = $(this),
        child  = parent.children('.child').first();
    child.detach();
    parent.empty().append(child);
});
```

What that does:

1. Moves from the set of `.child` elements up to the set of `.parent` elements. The resulting set will only have unique parents.
2. Loops through the parents.
3. Gets the **first** `.child` in each parent and detaches it.
4. Empties the `.parent`.
5. Re-attaches the `.child`.

End result is that each `.parent` will have only one `.child` (and no *other* children, whether `.child` or not).

Comment: Starting selector is always `$(this)`, which is `.child`, not a `.parent`

Comment: Not sure how can I use it inside `$(this)`

Comment: If the starting selector is always the child, the code could potentially run a lot of times. Is there a way to make the parent the starting selector?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that everything should be done inside `each()`. I've updated a question.

Comment: @Per Salbark no way, `each()` is always a `.child`

Comment: Yes, but in the first itteration you `empty()` the parent, removing all the other to come.

Comment: Not sure if I can `empty()` a parent when I work with it's child inside `each()`?

Comment: @Steve: Will there be more than one child element in a given parent with class `child`? Your example only shows one.

Comment: @Steve: Okay, but you still haven't answered my question: Will there be more than one child element **in a given parent** with class `child`?

Comment: @PerSalbark: The question only shows one `.child` child of each `.parent`. But I would do it as per my first code block rather than the starting point Steve seems to want to use.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: there can be more than one `.child` inside `.parent`, we keep only a first one. So If there are three, second and third should be removed.

Comment: How do I use it inside `each()`?

Comment: @Steve: I've updated it again to fix the starting point and to discard second and third `.child` elements in the `.parent`.

Comment: @Steve Just to mention: My [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976194/remove-everything-except-child/14976531#14976531) with the regex alternative has always only kept the first `.child` element in a `.parent` element and removed further `.child` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here you'd have a solution with pure JS: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHUdt/)

So within your loop you can use the following:

```
this.parentNode.innerHTML = this.outerHTML;
```

If you'd have to keep attached event handlers:

```
var _this = this.cloneNode(true),
    parent = this.parentNode;
parent.innerHTML = '';
parent.appendChild(_this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it;

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.child', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $parent = $this.parent(),
        $children = $parent.find('.child'); // or: $this.siblings('.child');

    $parent
        .empty() // Empty the "parent" element
        .append($children); // Re-append all "child" element to "parent"
    $this.focus(); // Focus the (input) element
});
```

Comment: Buggy if there are multiple `.child`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using a regex:

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().match("<input class=.child.>"));
});
```

Comment: This will fail with *all sorts* of content (`<input class="foo">My child likes ice cream` for instance), and makes a completely unnecessary round-trip through markup, thereby losing any event handlers or such attached to the children.

Comment: Corrected the code, but yes, event handlers are going to be lost like this.

Comment: And then there's Steve whole thing about how he wants to start with `items`, where `items` is the set of `.child` elements. (About half the back-and-forth on my answer was because he didn't want to do the simple thing I originally suggested, which also did `$(".parent").each` as yours does, but without the markup round-trip.)